# Declare @Table not getting recreated in while loop

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have a simple while loop and in the loop I am declaring a `DECLARE @TABLE` with one column and its data type is id. While the loop loops the records I am just inserting the values into the table variable. Whenever the loop is looping it the `Declare @TABLE` should get recreated and the old values should not exist. But its not happening. Below is the code

```
Declare @V int
Set @V = 1

While (@V <= 3)
begin

  DECLARE @Changes table
  (
    Id int
  )

  Insert into @Changes
  Values (@V)

  select * from @Changes

  SET @V=@V+1 
END
```

In normal we should get the output as

```
1

2

3
```

But the output i am getting is

```
1

1
2

1
2
3
```

Which is wrong.

Is this the normal behavior or a bug in SQL

Comment: Declare it outside the loop and truncate it in the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. T-SQL is a very odd language. Variable declarations affect when a variable can be referenced, but they don't actually participate in control flow.

Consider:

```
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
   DECLARE @a int
END

SET @a = 1
PRINT @a
```

Actually prints 1. It doesn't complain about an undeclared variable.

As Allan notes in the comments, if you want `@Changes` to be empty at the start of each loop, make it so:

```
Declare @V int

DECLARE @Changes table
(
  Id int
)
Set @V = 1

While (@V <= 3)
begin
  delete from @Changes

  Insert into @Changes
  Values (@V)

  select * from @Changes

  SET @V=@V+1 
END
```

Comment: I knew the answer should be deleting the table, but that should not be the normal scenario. I thought its a bug in SQL??

Comment: @user3309172 - it's not a bug, it's just the way that the T-SQL language works. `DECLARE` introduces a variable. From that point onwards in the batch, that variable can be used. It doesn't matter how/where the `DECLARE` is nested, and as I say, it does *not* take part in any control flow (such as `IF` or `WHILE`).